# Can I run scala script directly from git repo in databricks

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, git-repo, databricks-community-edition

I want to run a scala script as a job from my git repo in databricks. I am not able to see any option to do it. Do we need a special access to be able to do it?
I can see the option to run notebook from the git repo but cannot see the option to directly run script.

I can only see notebook and python script but not scala script

---

Comment: did you try to have your Scala code as notebook?